# Как почистить кеш в ASP.NET 4.5 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Залил обновление на сайт (сервер ISS 7). Всё то что во view обновилось, а контроллёры старые загружаются, а новые нет. Я удалил всё папку с контролами, а сайт всё равно работает как ни в чём не бывало. Как почистить кеш? Спасибо.

Comment: Рестарт сайта делали? На крайний случай - рестарт IIS.

Comment: сделал рестарт сервера, рестарт сайта, перезагрузил сам компьютер сервера. Сайт как работает так и работает, хотя я папку с контроллерами вообще снёс (во время перезагрузки сайт был недоступен разумеется).

Comment: а может это браузер закешировал? другим браузером открывать пробовали?

Comment: Глупый вопрос, но может не с тот папкой работаете? Было у меня один раз так - меняла код в одной папке, а проект оказывается опубликовался в другую...

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Я писал, что view обновления применились. Я могу их менять, редактировать и заливать. И на сайте меняется отображение нормально.Значит папка работает та что надо (других точно нет). Про браузер - пробовал другой, тоже самое. Всё работает. Хотя контроллеров нет (я их удалил через фтп). И на сервере ISS я перепроверил, этой папки нет Controller

Comment: Так контроллеры же компилируются в dll, которые лежат в папке bin, там и надо удалять...

Comment: аа не знал такого. щас попробую

Comment: Большое спасибо Ella Svetlaya. Удалил папку bin и залил снова + добавил удалённую папку Controller. Всё заработало с новым обновлением. Спасибо!!!

Comment: Отлично, а теперь удаляйте папку `Controller` с сервера обратно :) Нет, серьезно: как у вас вообще папка с исходным кодом оказалась на сервере? На сервере должна быть только статика и файлы, обрабатываемые ASP.NET непосредственно (`.aspx`, `.cshtml` и т.п.)

Comment: @PavelMayorov думаю папка просто копируется в ручную, вместо публикации проекта :)

Comment: Ну я думал в asp.net также как на php работает, грузит сайт из файлов. Получается надо удалить все файлы .cs с сервера?

Comment: @Ella Svetlaya я разрабатываю на asp.net порядка 9 месяцев. Но это мой первый опыт публикации сайта на сервере. Заливаю файлы как вы подметили по фтп, просто копируя всю папку с сайтом. Пробовал публиковать проект через visual studio, но мне показалось что половина файлов как то не загрузилось после публикации)))))) думал баг какой то. После этого вручную заливаю

Comment: Если проект на Winforms ASP.Net, то да, если в проекте предусмотрена публикация без компиляции, то можно просто папку копировать. Если же, как у Вас, проект ASP.Net MVC, то здесь необходима публикация (компиляция) проекта, в итоге останутся только библиотеки и файлы представлений. Я даже как-то пару лет назад спрашивала, можно ли без компиляции обойтись - https://toster.ru/q/23845 Однозначный ответ - нет!

Comment: Большое спасибо за информацию! Полезно.

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya - однозначно да! http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424722/

Comment: @PashaPash хитро-хитро, но MVC теряет смысл... :)

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya не теряет. но лучше обсуждать в том вопросе :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Контроллеры ASP MVC проекта при публикации компилируются в dll библиотеки и помещаются в папку bin. Чтобы изменения вступили в силу, замените скомпилированные файлы контроллеров в bin.

Answer (score 0):

На серваке почисти папку `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework(Framework64)\v.4.0.xxxxx\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?