# Работа с контроллерами ASP.NET MVC без их компиляции (редактирование на лету, как в ASP.Net WebForms)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Делаю в основном веб-проекты на ASP.Net Webforms. 
Сейчас начала делать проект на ASP.NET MVC 4. Возник такой вопрос.
В ASP.Net WebForms есть возможность публикации сайта, не компилируя проект (например, директория bin может быть вообще пуста). А все исходники размещаются в директории сайта. IIS компилирует проект на лету. И если возникает необходимость быстро исправить что-либо в коде, я просто открываю файл *.cs в Блокноте, изменяю что требуется, и присохранении IIS сам перекомпилирует проект при следующем обращении к нему.

Можно ли что-то подобное сделать в ASP.NET MVC, т.к. когда я делаю Publish, Studio компилирует весь код в dll, оставляя доступными мне только view'шки, не давая на лету редактировать код контроллеров и моделей.

<sub>кросспост неотвеченного вопроса от [@Ella Svetlaya](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179703/ella-svetlaya) с https://toster.ru/q/23845</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Естественно, можно. Сам механизм компиляции и выполнения ASP.NET со времен Web Forms не поменялся. Поменялся только фреймворк верхнего уровня.

MVC-приложение (не-vnext!) без предварительной компиляции вполне можно запустить, хоть это и лишает возможности использовать нормальные инструменты.

Из нового шаблона проекта вырезали движок WebForms, а поддержки аттрибута `codefile` в razor нет. Но код View и так принято писать прямо во View, так что тут разницы с обычным приложением MVC никакой.

`Views\Home\Index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div>
    @Model
</div>
```

регистрируем роуты. `global.asax`:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc" %>

<script runat="server" language="C#">
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var routes = RouteTable.Routes;

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
</script>
```

создаем `bin`, складываем в него файлы из стандартного mvc:

```
System.Web.Mvc.dll
System.Web.Mvc.xml
System.Web.Optimization.dll
System.Web.Optimization.xml
System.Web.Razor.dll
System.Web.Razor.xml
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.xml
System.Web.WebPages.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.xml
System.Web.WebPages.xml
```

Осталось придумать куда положить контроллер. В ASP.NET все еще работает механизим [общих папок кода](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t990ks23(v=vs.100).aspx).

`App_Code\HomeController.cs`:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace NonCompiledMvc.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View((object)"It Works!");
        }
    }
}
```

Копируем `Web.config` и `Views\Web.config` из чистого проекта ASP.NET MVC. Добавляем `favicon.ico`.

Создаем Application в IIS с корнем в этой папке. Открываем - It Works!

Можно создать в той же папке проект для Visual Studio и просто добавить в него все файлы (только зависимости в `bin` лучше подключать через `nuget`).

Чтобы студия не выреала cs-файлы при публикации достаточно поменять у них в свойствах `Build Type` c `Compile` на `Content`.

[полный код примера](https://github.com/PashaPash/NonCompiledMvc)

Но лучше все-таки подождать vnext.

Comment: Нарушение самого принципа MVC :) С таким подходом уж лучше тогда Webforms проект делать.

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya чем это нарушает MVC? Это всего-лишь изменения момента компиляции, оно никак не затрагивает разделение на MVC. Посмотрите на asp.net vnext - там все по умолчанию лежит исходниками, и все компилируется в момент старта. Даже внешние зависимости. И это - основная (!) фича ASP.NET vnext

Comment: ну vnext тоже жду с нетерпением )

Comment: Код не должен быть во view. Считаю это не правильно. Хотя грешу, бывает :)

Comment: Но ставлю +1 за ответ, действительно, почему бы не реализовать и такое решение.

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya в примере все ок, код - в контроллере. просто контроллер лежит в папке App_Code, а не во View -  все по честному, без обмана :) про app_code и темный век web sites вместо web apps мало кто сейчас помнит. но механизм все еще работает.

Comment: пожалуй, соглашусь :)